# CIVICRM, how to make first or last name optional in contacts?

Tags: civicrm

I'm Use civicrm with drupal, and I import data in to contact but my data have some row missing  first or last name, and first or last name is compulsory so its not uploaded,

So where is back-end setting for civi where I'm make first or last name optional,
Is that possible?

Comment: Hi Wiram - just re-iterating what Joe said :)

Answer (score 5):

By default, there are two tests that are run before creating a contact in CiviCRM. You only have to pass ONE of these two tests for the contact to be created.

1) Do they have a first name and a last name
OR
2) Do they have an email.

There is NOT a "back-end setting for civi where [you can] make first or last name optional" but if you have an email address for that contact, it will not be required.

One work around if you need to import contacts that don't have either an email or a first name and last name is to create a dummy email address like 'dummy@example.com' and add this to the data that you are going to import.

Comment: I'm not able to find this setting, where is it?

Comment: This functionality has changed a bit since May 2013. Currently it is found in 4.5.4 at http://yourdomain.org/civicrm/contact/deduperules?action=update&id=1. To change it you need to create a new Individual Match Rule with just email, say, and then set the Supervised Rule to it. HTH.

Comment: Wiriam - you said: "I'm not able to find this setting". I said "There is NOT a "back-end setting".

Answer (score 1):

This is hacky, but use a spreadsheet to insert "FixThisName" or some findable text and import. You can search and edit in Civi after.